# ABSPATH or __FILE__?

Tags: php, wordpress

Can someone tell me if either of these two methods has an advantage over the other and why?

`$mydir = ABSPATH.'/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images';`

`$mydir = dirname(__FILE__).'/images';`

They can both be used to obtain and absolute path to the images directory of "mytheme" regardless of structure of whether wordpress is installed on the root directory or in a subdirectory off the root. In both cases, they are being called from the functions.php file which is located under the "mytheme" folder.

Comment: There's an answer by @Adam which trumps mine in quality, consider changing the accepted answer

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would personally prefer `dirname()` as it is always guaranteed to give me the correct result, while the ABSPATH method relies on a fixed theme path and theme name that can both change.

By the way, you can use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: Note that `__FILE__` and `__DIR__` sometimes gives unwanted results if you use symbolic links, since by design the `__FILE__` *resolves* the symbolic links. Unfortunately there is no way to circumvent this and various ways to fix this in the PHP itself is proposed in [PHP's bugs tracker](https://bugs.php.net/search.php?cmd=display&search_for=__FILE__+symbolic).

Answer (score 13):

- The path to the "wp-content" directory and its subdirectories [can be different](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content_folder) in a particular WordPress installation. Also, using the WordPress internal constants (such as `ABSPATH`) is not recommended. See the [Determining Plugin and Content Directories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories) WordPress Codex article.
- Since PHP 4.0.2, [symlinks are being resolved](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php#constant.file) for the `__FILE__` and `__DIR__` magic constants, so take that into account.

  **Bottom line**: To determine the absolute path to a theme directory, I would suggest to use the [`get_template_directory()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) function which also [applies filters](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/theme.php#L251) and internally combines [`get_theme_root()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_root) and [`get_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template).

Answer (score 3):

For my own projects I would choose `dirname(__FILE__)`, also there is a new constant in PHP:

```
__DIR__ === dirname(__FILE__)
```

Comment: The `__FILE__` const exists since PHP 4, while the `__DIR__` const is only since PHP 5.3. Worth noting, if you expect to work with anything older than 5.3

Answer (score 0):

ABSPATH is defined variable -> define("ABSPATH",`__FILE__`);
if i directly use magic constant `__FILE__` .it will produce same result.

In CMS ABSPATH and framework use BASEPATH is used to get root information in the form of defined variable .
In the end with the help of both we get same accurate result.